# Why isn't the cube's collision properties working?

Tags: particles

[image]

You can see the particles in the above image, but, despite the cube having had "collision" properties in the settings, it won't block the particles?

[image]

...and here's the physics settings I'm using.
[image]

Here is the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByScwSCTIaUGUkZoTXhoTFhjU3c/edit?usp=sharing
Many thanks

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the physics tab, too (last tab on the right)? I can't download the blendfile where I am, but I think those physics settings are the only other thing I'd need to see.

Comment: @Matt Sure Here: http://pbrd.co/1bxDXD4

Comment: Hmmm...that's not what I expected to see... I don't think any of those settings should be causing any problems. You might also check the physics settings on the particles. IIRC, there's a way to specify whether or not the particles interact with collision meshes. Another thing to check is that you are using enough subframes (usually not necessary, but for fast motion, it can help to calculate 2-3 subframes).

Comment: I tried your blend in 2.69, and the cube is blocking the particles for me as you expected, even with 0 subframes for the particles.  Is it possible your particles are "Baked" and you need to free them (in your particle system in the Cache settings)?

Comment: @PhillipKinkade Sorry, I couldn't answer yesterday, but thanks for your suggestion! I'll have a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This reproducable as Phillip Kinkade mentioned, when the particle system animation was baked without the collision object, later adding wouldn't make them collide.

1. Free Bake
2. Position your collision object
3. Bake

[image]

After the three steps above no more particles will go through the cube:

[image]